# Как с помощью php перезаписать в div другой текст?

Tags: php

Есть например такой блок
`<div class='item-name'>Текст</div>`, как с помощью php перезаписать в div другой текст?

Comment: функция preg_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим, есть переменная хранящая требуемый текст для вывода его в блоке.

```
$text = "Сегодня хороший день";
```

Для вывода в `html` необходимо выбрать один из вариантов и вставить его в нужном месте:

1. `<?=$text;?>`
2. `<? echo $text;?>`
3. `<?php echo $text;?>`

Таким образом, используя самый короткий вариант (1), выведем содержимое переменной `$text` с текстом:

```
<div class='item-name'><?=$text;?></div>
```